# Java charset encoding for values > 128

Tags: java, arrays, string, unicode, character-encoding

We have one application which encrypts a string password and pass it on to other application for decrypt. Strategy is:

If password is "demoString~", it's byte array representation is:

```
[100, 101, 109, 111, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 126]
```

My application rotates this string to take its mirror image. Then takes byte representation of every character and adds "1" into it.
        So final reverted string is "xhojsuTpnfe" (where first character x is some invalid character, which can not be copied or pasted) and its byte representation looks like:

```
[127, 104, 111, 106, 115, 117, 84, 112, 110, 102, 101]
```

My application then sends this rotated/modified string to another application, which simply decrypts it by rotating it to take mirror image and substract digit 1 from byte code of each character.

Now the problem happens, when I use characters like "~". Its byte code value is 127. Adding 1 into it, it becomes 128. and there is no character to represent byte code value 128. Then my application sends invalid character to other application and other application can not decrypt it. Both applications use charset "ISO-8859-1".

This issue can be tested using this sample java code:

```
package com.demo;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RotetePwd {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        final String stringPwd = "demoString~";
        final String encoding = "ISO-8859-1";

        byte[] origByteArray = stringPwd.getBytes(encoding);
        byte[] rotatedByteArray = new byte[origByteArray.length];

        for (int i = origByteArray.length; i > 0; i--)
            rotatedByteArray[rotatedByteArray.length - i] = (byte) (origByteArray[i - 1] + 1);

        System.out.println("Original password: " + new String(origByteArray, encoding));
        System.out.println("Original password byte array: " + Arrays.toString(origByteArray));
        System.out.println("Plain rotated password: " + new String(rotatedByteArray, encoding));
        System.out.println("Plain rotated password byte array: " + Arrays.toString(rotatedByteArray));
    }
}
```

Output looks like:

[image]

Please let me know, how to solve this issue. I tried with UTF-8 charset, but didnt work. Then I tried UTF-16, but it prints some garbage characters. Can I use some other charset to support all characters (even greater than 127)?

Comment: Where is the problem here? ISO-8859-1 is known to support all byte values from 0 to 255... But if you want to stay in same range (say [32-126]), just pretend 126+1 = 32 and 32-1 = 126. BTW 127 is the code of Del control character, `~` has code 126...

Comment: I can't as decrypted value is further used to authenticate against one system. I should be able to retrieve original string as it is :(

Comment: @SergeBallesta: ISO-8859-1 does not support characters between 127-159: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Comment: All depends what you mean by *support*. There are no printable characters there, but *by definition* they are the unicode control characters of same value. And all characters below 255 do have a meaning except for U+0080 and U+0081 that are marked as *unassigned* ([ref.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF)). More precisely, conversion of java characters of code below 255 to  ISO-8859-1 encoded bytes keep the same value.

Comment: Passwprds need to be handles correctly, they are user secrets and user expect correct handling, this scheme meis trivial to compromise. In general **do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ISO-8859-1 is actually a character encoding with 256 valid<sup>1</sup> codes.  And 127 is a valid code in ISO-8859-1.

The tilde character (`~`) has code 126  (not 127!) in ISO-8859-1 (and ASCII, and even UTF-8<sup>2</sup>).  When you add one to it you get 127.  That is the ASCII `DEL` character (in all of the above character encodings), and it is not printable.

The real problem here is that your encryption scheme *as you have designed it* takes no account of this.

There are a few solutions, including the following:

1. Don't convert the encrypted bytes to a String.
2. Don't print the String.
3. Change the encryption scheme so that every printable character is encrypted to a printable character.  For example, if you want to be able to handle only the ASCII printing characters, then you can map (`~`) to the space character ().
4. When you convert the encoded bytes to characters using something like base64 encoding to guarantee that all characters are printable.

---

<sup>1 - Actually, it depends on precisely which specification you are using.  According to Wikipedia, in ISO/IEC 8859-1 codes less than 32 and from 127 to 159 are "undefined".  However, it is common to treat ISO 8859-1 as synonymous with Latin-1 (aka Unicode code block zero).  In Latin-1, these codes are defined to be control codes or extended control codes.</sup>

<sup>2 - There is another issue with UTF-8.  All code units greater than 127 get encoded as multi-byte sequences.  Conversely, any byte greater than 127 in a valid UTF-8 encoding will be part of a multi-byte codepoint.  So, if you turn a sequence of encrypted bytes into a String by pretending that it is a UTF-8 sequence, the result will be "garbage"; i.e. mixture of printable and  unprintable characters, and undefined / unmappable subsequences which won't decode.  Depending on what you do with the "faux UTF-8" byte sequence, you may get data loss.</sup>

Comment: @zaph - actually, 127 is fine.  But you are correct that codepoints above 127 are encoded as 2 or more bytes in UTF-8

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I need. I somehow thought once that approach needs to be changed. But how? Didn't have any idea! Many thanks for your guidance!

Answer (score 1):

When adding 1, use modulu 128.
This way, when you have the byte code value 127, it will be turned into 0.

Comment: Oups, I really wonder whether code 0 (C null character) will be better processed that 128...

Answer (score 1):

When you do byte-value-manipulations treat everything as `byte[]`, not as character (just like every modern encryption-method). If you need to pass it via a char-only channel use Base64-encoding to get a String-representation of your `byte[]`.

If you want to restrict your "encryption"-method to char-operations, try to define it in terms of characters instead of byte-values.

P.S.: Btw. I wouldn't view your method as "encryption" but rather as "obfuscation" - it is no longer cleartext, but it can easily be broken (e.g. with a single known plaintext). Why not use some proven encryption-algorithm like AES with a shared key on both sides of the connection?